# Google MDL Lite : How can I progmmatically init a checkbox or switch?

Tags: javascript, html, material-design-lite

in google's material design lite framework When I load this HTML into the page sometime after its already loaded I don't see the nice little switch like i do if this HTML was present before the library was loaded.

https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#toggles-section

```
<label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch-1" class="mdl-switch__input" checked>
  <span class="mdl-switch__label"></span>
</label>
```

is there a function I can run to init the elements as they appear? I have searched for hours with failure as my only result :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found out how to update `registered` components by reading the .js file.

```
componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered()
```